# Post запрос в формате json на android

Tags: post, android, json

Как отправить post запрос, для следующего формата:

```
    "type":"edit_user",             обязательное
"user_data":{
    "access_key":"XXXX",        обязательное
    "pass":"",                  пароль зашифрованный md5. сам пароль не делжен быть меньше 6 символов
    "email":"",
    "surname":"",
    "name":"",
    "patronymic":"",
    "birthdate":"",             в формате timestamp
    "pol":""                    0- мужской, 1-женский
}
```

C первой парой понятно, можно  использовать обычный json.put, который принимает формать поле-значение, а как быть с массивом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `put` у `JSONObject` (как я понял, речь идёт именно о нём) может принимать также и `JSONArray` и `JSONObject` в качестве аргумента.

Comment: Это я понимаю, я не понимаю в каком формате ему предоставить эти данные. Получается так
json.put("имя_параметра", jsonArray)

Comment: Да, именно так.